# Convert clause for with Set<Map<String, Object>> to clause forEach

Tags: for-loop, foreach, java-8

I have the follow method:

```
protected Set<Map<String, Object>> joinQueryResults(Set<Map<String, Object>> resultEmpty, Set<Map<String, Object>> resultWithValues){
    for(Map<String, Object> mapEmpty: resultEmpty){         
        for(Map<String, Object> mapValue: resultWithValues){
            if (mapValue.get("name").equals(mapEmpty.get("name"))){
                mapEmpty.replace("totfailed", mapValue.get("totfailed"));
                mapEmpty.replace("totsuccess", mapValue.get("totsuccess"));
                break;
            }       
        }   
    }       
    return resultEmpty; 
}
```

How could this be converted to a forEach clause? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating shared mutable variables in a stream is frowned upon. This should do it.

```
resultEmpty.stream().forEach(empty -> {
  resultWithValues.stream()
      .filter(
          withValues -> withValues.get("name").equals(empty.get("name")))
      .findFirst().ifPresent(withValues -> {
        empty.replace("totsuccess", withValues.get("totsuccess"));
        empty.replace("totfailed", withValues.get("totfailed"));
      });
});
```